# Reference Microsoft code of service application is not thread-safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, windows-services

I'm developing a windows app that should run as a service, and I use this publication for it:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540475(v=vs.85).aspx

But isn't it thread-unsafe? If I understand correctly, ReportSvcStatus (that uses global variables gSvcStatus and gSvcStatusHandler) is called from SvcInit and from SvcCtrlHandler, that runs in a different thread. But it doesn't take any locks...
So why is it safe to use this code?

Comment: So, if the service is shut down before init is called, the message is lost?

Comment: Well, no, it looks like here the thread-sync is acheived by the fact that the call to ReportSvcStatus in SvcInit is guaranteed to run after call to SvcCtrlHandler triggers a message.
But theoretically, if for some reason two control messages arrive very fast, it can be the case that the value reported to ReportSvcStatus may be corrupted

Comment: Actually, after looking more attentive to the page mentioned, there's already someone who mentioned a possible RC there in comments=) However, the comment is unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is *nearly* thread-safe, because the main thread and the callback thread use the global variables at different times - the main thread during service startup, the callback thread only once the service is running, and the main thread again when the service is shutting down.

However, the second call to `ReportSvcStatus` from the callback thread during handling of a stop request might conflict with the call to `ReportSvcStatus` in the main thread after the stop event is signaled.  In practice, it may be unlikely that the main thread would respond to the event quickly enough for this to be a problem; I'm not sure.  I'm also not sure what the purpose of that second call is; it appears to be redundant.  Removing it should eliminate that race condition.

I believe there is also a potential race condition if a stop request is received immediately after the service status is set to running, before the call to `SetServiceStatus` returns, although this would be even less likely to occur in practice.  This could be eliminated by protecting the contents of `ReportSvcStatus` with a critical section.

There may also be some multicore (memory caching) issues - these are subtler to reason about.  I believe the use of a critical section in `ReportSvcStatus` would also address these, at least on existing CPU platforms.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly my concern=) So, I should protect the global variables with some sort of mutex (or just use local variables)

Comment: Now that you mention it, yes - if you remove the extraneous call to `ReportSvcStatus` (just after setting the stop event) I don't think you need any global variables.  Even the use of a global counter for `dwCheckPoint` is wrong - it defeats the purpose, since it hides whether the service is really making progress or not.  (It should be an argument to `ReportSvcStatus` instead.)